# Please add a tag for griddb

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

I am seeking help to create a tag for `griddb`. Please check ( [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/griddb/info) ) on SO. I have posted question on DBA.SE that would cover in `griddb` tag. Currently I have used `query` tag because that's the closest one available.

I request to create the `griddb` tag so the question I have posted on DBA.SE would go in `griddb` tag

[How to select and group values from a SQL Database column using GridDB Python Client](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312892/how-to-select-and-group-values-from-a-sql-database-column-using-griddb-python-cl)

[How to store 2 different databases in a single GridDB container](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/313104/how-to-store-2-different-databases-in-a-single-griddb-container)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I have recreated the tag, with reservations.

Please be aware the tag will only live as long as there is at least one visible question associated with it.

If the community here determines that [griddb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/griddb) questions are not adding value to the site, questions may be closed and ultimately deleted. Once the last question is deleted, the tag will go away as well.

This is what happened before: Previous questions associated with [griddb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/griddb) were not well-received at all, most of them being fairly transparent attempts at [astroturfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing). We will not tolerate that sort of activity at all.

I also note very few GridDB questions get good **answers** even on Stack Overflow. Perhaps the experience here will be different.

Ultimately, the quantity and quality of **answers** will determine the fate of this tag.

Your best chance of success is to encourage people who can provide high quality answers to GridDB questions to participate here. The questions and answers should further the [aims of this site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour):

> **Database Administrators** is a question and answer site for database professionals. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of expert answers to advanced database-related questions.

Emphasis on **library of expert answers to advanced database-related questions**.

We are not interested in hosting unanswered questions about every niche product just for the sake of it.